# Can't sync contact & calendar to iOS 4.1 device since Mavericks update

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, contacts, calendar

I just installed Mavericks. I have an old iPhone 3GS and it is running iOS 4.1.

Since updating to Mavericks, iTunes syncs everything but Address Book and Calendar, however under OS X 10.8 everything was syncing fine.

Do I need to do something special to make it sync above things?
Am I the only one with the issue?

Additional information: It seems like there is no option in iTunes for contacts and calendar synchronization either. It is like it just disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to sync contacts and calender, you have to use iCloud now.

With iTunes 11.1.2 and OS X Mavericks they(Apple) disabled the option to sync locally according [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12117) Document.

> Note:   These instructions apply only if you use OS X v.10.8.5 or earlier. If you use OS X Mavericks v.10.9 or later, your contacts, calendars, and other info are updated on your computers and iOS devices via iCloud. For more information, see iCloud Help at icloud.com.

Comment: You are right. But what a bullsh*t apple pulled. I mean I don't have iCloud (old phone) nor I want to use it... Now there is no way to Sync contacts.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. So I wrote a small open source app for myself, as a temporary workaround.

It's in the iOS AppStore now, for free:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/devicesync-for-ios/id737867459?mt=8

Please read the AppStore app description before using it!

In the current form it simply "copies" calendar entries from iOS to OS X, deleting calendar entries on OS X first.

Thus, be sure to add and update your calendar entries on iOS only!

But still, this works well enough for me.

Three days ago, I pushed version 1.1 to the iOS AppStore, should be available sometime next week. It makes the "sync" time range configurable.

As time permits, I will add support for contact synchronization and improve merging behavior of calendar entries.

You have to get the corresponding OS X app from https://github.com/yep/DeviceSync-for-OS-X/releases

Please open the OS X app by holding the control (ctrl) key and then double-clicking the icon. For more information, see https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5290.

This app is open source and hence a collaborative effort. If you are a developer or know some iOS developers, feel free to add missing functionality (send a pull request at github).

See https://github.com/yep/DeviceSync-for-OS-X and https://github.com/yep/DeviceSync-for-iOS

> I have an old iPhone 3GS and it is running iOS 4.1.

Now iOS 4.1 is a problem: it does not support ARC. I think it should be possible to update to 6.1 on the 3gs. It would be a lot easier to port this app to 6.1 than to 4.1